# What is (if any) the generalization of the concept of a basis for ideals of rings?

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

This question is motivated by the following problem from a problem set on ring theory:

> Prove that, if $R$ is a Noetherian commutative ring, and $I$ is its ideal, $R/I$ is a again Noetherian.

My first thought was: "of course, let $a_{1}, ..., a_{n}$ be a minimal generating set of $I$. Let $b_{1}, ..., b_{n'}$ be a minimal generating set of some other ideal $J$. Since the ring is commutative, $I\cap J$ is again an ideal, which is, again, finitely generated, since the ring is Noetherian, so there is some common set of generators $c_{1},...,c_{k}$ that belong to both $I$ and $J$ and generate $I\cap J$, and that set can be extended to both a generating set of $I$, $c_{1},\cdots, c_{k}, \alpha_{k+1}, \cdots, \alpha_{l}$ and a generating set of $J$, $c_{1}, \cdots, c_{k}, \beta_{k+1}, \cdots, \beta_{m}$, in such a way that no linear combination of $\alpha_{i}$'s and $c_{i}$'s with coefficients in $R$ gives an element $\beta_{j}$. Then $\pi(\beta_{1}), \cdots, \pi(\beta_{l})$ is a generating set of $\pi(J)$, where $\pi$ is the canonical projection $\pi: R \to R/I$."

If generating sets were working like bases, and ideals like subspaces, this would prove the statement, since $\alpha_{i}$ are "linearly independent" from $\beta_{j}$, and projections don't create new subspaces. In this case, I realized that in some of the previous problem sets there was a task to prove that, if $\phi: R_{1}\to R_{2}$ is a surjective morphism of rings, there is a bijection between ideals of $R_{2}$ and ideals of $R_{1}$ containing the kernel of $\phi$, which in this case gives a bijection between ideals of $R/I$ and ideals of $R$ containing $I$, so there is no need for considering the part containing $\alpha_{i}$, and the projections of $\beta_{i}$ indeed form generating sets in all ideals of $R/I$, proving $R/I$ to be Noetherian.

But this made me wondering, what properties of bases generalize to generating sets of ideals? Is it true, for instance, that, if $I \subset J$ and $I, J$ are finitely generated ideals, a minimal generating set of $I$ has smaller size than a minimal generating set of $J$? Does a minimal generating set of an ideal have to have a fixed number of elements, and does it then make any sense to talk of dimension of an ideal? Is it always true that a minimal generating set of a subideal can be extended to a minimal generating set of the bigger ideal? If two ideals, $I, J$ have linearly independent minimal generating sets, i.e. no element of one is a linear combination of another, and vice versa, is it true that $\pi(I)\cong I$ when we factor by $J$?  What are, in general, the useful properties of bases of linear spaces that generalize to generating sets, and what properties do not?

**Edit:** Of course, I mean the ideals not coinciding with the ring itself, since for a ring $R$ $\langle 1_{R}\rangle = R$ and the answers to almost all questions are obviously negative.

Comment: You are looking for modules over a ring (see wiki for example)

Comment: I know what a module over a ring is, I am not asking about generalizations of vector spaces with rings instead of fields, I am asking about rings themselves.

Comment: A ring is a module over itself (with obvious scalar multiplication) and the submodules are exactly the ideals of the ring so what you're asking is just a particular case of modules over a ring.

Comment: Yes, I know that as well, and I am asking precisely because this is a very particular case of a module, and it likely has many properties that generic modules do not.

Comment: Why don't you work directly with the standard definition of a Noetherian ring: namely one in which every increasing chain of ideals is finite?

Comment: The question is not about Noetherian rings. If you read the text carefully, you'll notice that I solved the original problem, and it was just a motivation for the question.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it true, for instance, that, if $I \subset J$ and $I,J$ are finitely generated ideals, a minimal generating set of $I$ has smaller size than a minimal generating set of $J$?

No: $\langle X^2, Y^2 \rangle \subsetneq \langle 1 \rangle = R[X, Y]$

> [...] does it then make any sense to talk of dimension of an ideal?

It should help to look [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29993/rank-of-a-module), [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/73903/rank-of-a-module), [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/153659/different-definitions-of-the-rank-of-a-module), and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/221489/rank-versus-free-rank-of-a-module)

> Is it always true that a minimal generating set of a subideal can be extended to a minimal generating set of the bigger ideal?

If by 'extend' here one means 'taking unions *while preserving* linear independence', then no:

$\langle X^2 \rangle \subsetneq \langle X \rangle \subsetneq R[X, Y]$

Comment: Yes, probably need to add "for ideals not coinciding with the whole ring"

Comment: Why the ideal generated by $X$ in $R[X,Y]$ is not an ideal in $R[X,Y]$? I seem to misunderstand the meaning of this sign.

Comment: @DaigakunoBaku I'm sorry, I don't understand this last question; it is an ideal, of course, the point being that the only way to 'pass' from $\langle X^2 \rangle$ to the bigger $\langle X \rangle$ is to add $X$ as a generator, but then $\{X^2, X\}$ are not independent, so I don't think the notion of 'extending' makes sense as in the vector space bases one

Comment: Thanks, now I understand. Yes, that answers the question about extension of generating sets, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it true, for instance, that, if $I \subset J$ and $I,J$ are finitely generated ideals, a minimal generating set of $I$ has smaller size than a minimal generating set of $J$?

> **Edit:** Of course, I mean the ideals not coinciding with the ring itself, since for a ring $R$ $\langle 1_{R}\rangle = R$ and the answers to almost all questions are obviously negative.

No: $(X^2,XY)\subset (X)\subset \mathbb{K}[X,Y]$

> Does a minimal generating set of an ideal have to have a fixed number of elements, and does it then make any sense to talk of dimension of an ideal?

No: $\mathbb{Z}=(1)=(2,3)$. 
Another example: $(6,8)=(2)\subset \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Please, read the question. __if__ $I\subset J$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment. $(X+Y)$ is contained in $(X,Y)$, right?

Comment: Then I don't understand your notation. What do you mean by this "subset with a crossing" sign?

Comment: Strictly contained, I'll change the notation. I think the same is true for the other answer.

Comment: By $I\subset J$ I mean "$I$ is a proper subset of $J$". How is $(X + Y)\subset (X, Y)$ a counterexample to "$I \subset J \Rightarrow$ a minimal generating set of $I$ is smaller than a minimal generating set of $J$"? The generating set of $(X + Y)$ has one element, the generating set of (X, Y) has two. $\mathbb{K}[X, Y]$ is the whole ring, so, see the edit. The same thing with $(1)=\mathbb{Z}$ - again, see the edit.

Comment: You are right, I'm sorry.  I got confused. For $(1)=\mathbb{Z}$ consider the second example I posted.

Comment: Thank you, yes, this is a counterexample

Comment: I've changed the example regarding the first question. It should be ok now